# How can I loop a command that adds a column to a data frame?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to add a dummy variable for each year, with the value 1 if a person was retired in that year and the value 0 otherwise. So far I've been doing this:

```
df$DummyRetired1987 <- with(df, ifelse(Empl_1987 == 4, 1, 0))
df$DummyRetired1988 <- with(df, ifelse(Empl_1988 == 4, 1, 0))
df$DummyRetired1989 <- with(df, ifelse(Empl_1989 == 4, 1, 0))
df$DummyRetired1990 <- with(df, ifelse(Empl_1990 == 4, 1, 0))
df$DummyRetired1991 <- with(df, ifelse(Empl_1991 == 4, 1, 0))
df$DummyRetired1992 <- with(df, ifelse(Empl_1992 == 4, 1, 0))
```

And that works fine, but I'm aware that there must be a much cleaner way to do this, probably as a for loop.

I've tried this:

```
for(year in c(1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992)){
  nam1 <- paste("df$DummyRetired", year, sep = "")
  nam2 <- paste("Empl_", year, sep = "")

  assign(nam1, with(df, ifelse(nam2 == 4, 1, 0)))
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the columns of interest ('nm1') with `grep`, create new column names with `paste` and assign the output of logical expression converted to binary

```
nm1 <-  grep("^Empl_\\d+$", names(df), value = TRUE)
nm2 <- paste0("DummyRetired", sub("\\D+", "", nm1))
df[nm2] <- +(df[nm1] == 4)
```

---

If we need a loop

```
for(i in seq_along(nm1)) {
      df[[nm2[i]]] <- as.integer(df[[nm1[i]]] == 4)
 }
```